# Animation Handling Problem by eventListeners

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this problem, although it seems to run fine in the snippet below for some reason.

I want the START to do the same animation as EXIT when I click it, but what happens is:

1. If the mouse is on it its like it does half the animation and then stops.
2. If the mouse leaves after clicking it just stops.

I ran the code in Chrome and tried Mozilla as well with the same result. I'm really surprised why it worked fine in the snippet. I have tried many things like removing listeners, simplifying animations etc., but nothing worked.

```js
function TogleAnimationStart(){
    document.getElementById('Start').style.animation = "WhenHover 0.4s infinite, Lighting 0s 0s infinite, MenuMove 0s 0s infinite"
}
function TogleAnimationOptions(){
    document.getElementById('Options').style.animation = "WhenHover 0.4s infinite, Lighting 0s 0s infinite, MenuMove 0s 0s infinite "
}
function TogleAnimationExit(){
    document.getElementById('Exit').style.animation = "WhenHover 0.4s infinite, Lighting 0s 0s infinite, MenuMove 0s 0s infinite"
}
function TogleIdleMenu(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.animation = "Lighting 4s linear infinite, MenuMove 2.5s infinite"
}

function Intro(){
    document.getElementById('Start').style.animation = "Lighting 4s linear infinite, MenuMove 2.5s infinite"
    document.getElementById('Options').style.animation = "Lighting 5s linear infinite, MenuMove 2.5s infinite"
    document.getElementById('Exit').style.animation = "Lighting 4s linear infinite, MenuMove 2.5s infinite"
    document.getElementById('Start').addEventListener("click", StartGame)
    document.getElementById('Start').addEventListener("mouseover", TogleAnimationStart)
    document.getElementById('Options').addEventListener("mouseover", TogleAnimationOptions)
    document.getElementById('Exit').addEventListener("mouseover", TogleAnimationExit)
    document.getElementById('Start').addEventListener("mouseout", function(){TogleIdleMenu('Start')})
    document.getElementById('Options').addEventListener("mouseout", function(){TogleIdleMenu('Options')})
    document.getElementById('Exit').addEventListener("mouseout", function(){TogleIdleMenu('Exit')})
}

function StartGame(){
    document.getElementById('Start').style.animation = "Bye 1s 0.2s 1"
    document.getElementById('Options').style.animation = "ByeOptions 1s 0.2s 1"
    document.getElementById('Exit').style.animation = "Bye 1s 0.2s 1"
}

window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    document.getElementById("GameFrame").addEventListener("click", Intro, { once: true }) 
})
```

```css
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #031321;
}

#Start,#Options,#Exit{
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffd70080;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 40px;

    display: block;
    margin: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 4px double #8B008B;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;
    left: 250px; 
    top: 350px;
}

#GameFrame{
    background: black;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    width: 850px;
    position: relative;
}

@keyframes WhenHover{
    0%{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 43px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #ffd700,  0 0 60px #ffd700,  0 0 160px #ffd700;
    color:  #ffd700;
    filter: brightness(85%);
    background: #8B008B;
    box-shadow: 0 0 300px #8B008B, 0 0 600px #8B008B, 0 0 160px #8B008B;
    }
    25%{
        top: 354px; 
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 43px;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #ffd700,  0 0 60px #ffd700,  0 0 160px #ffd700;
        color:  #ffd700;
        filter: brightness(85%);
        background: #8B008B;
        box-shadow: 0 0 300px #8B008B, 0 0 600px #8B008B, 0 0 160px #8B008B;
    }
    50%{
        top: 358px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 43px;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #ffd700,  0 0 60px #ffd700,  0 0 160px #ffd700;
        color:  #ffd700;
        filter: brightness(85%);
        background: #8B008B;
        box-shadow: 0 0 300px #8B008B, 0 0 600px #8B008B, 0 0 160px #8B008B;
    }
    75%{
        top: 354px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 43px;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #ffd700,  0 0 60px #ffd700,  0 0 160px #ffd700;
        color:  #ffd700;
        filter: brightness(85%);
        background: #8B008B;
        box-shadow: 0 0 300px #8B008B, 0 0 600px #8B008B, 0 0 160px #8B008B;
    }
    100%{
        top: 350px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 43px;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #ffd700,  0 0 60px #ffd700,  0 0 160px #ffd700;
        color:  #ffd700;
        filter: brightness(85%);
        background: #8B008B;
        box-shadow: 0 0 300px #8B008B, 0 0 600px #8B008B, 0 0 160px #8B008B;
    }
}

@keyframes Lighting{
    0%{text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #ffd70080,  0 0 18px #ffd70080,  0 0 46px #ffd70080; box-shadow: 0 0 21px #8B008B;}
    10%{top: 349px; text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #ffd70080,  0 0 19px #ffd70080,  0 0 45px #ffd70080; box-shadow: 0 0 20px #8B008B;}
    20%{top: 351px; text-shadow: 0px 0px 9px #ffd70080,  0 0 20px #ffd70080,  0 0 43px #ffd70080; box-shadow: 0 0 19px #8B008B;}
    30%{top: 349px; text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ffd70080,  0 0 21px #ffd70080,  0 0 42px #ffd70080; box-shadow: 0 0 18px #8B008B;}
    40%{top: 351px; text-shadow: 0px 0px 11px #ffd70080,  0 0 22px #ffd70080,  0 0 41px #ffd70080; box-shadow: 0 0 17px #8B008B;}
    50%{top: 349px; text-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #ffd70080,  0 0 23px #ffd70080,  0 0 40px #ffd70080; box-shadow: 0 0 16px #8B008B;}
    60%{top: 351px; text-shadow: 0px 0px 11px #ffd70080,  0 0 22px #ffd70080,  0 0 41px #ffd70080; box-shadow: 0 0 15px #8B008B;}
    70%{top: 349px; text-shadow: 0px 0px 9px #ffd70080,  0 0 21px #ffd70080,  0 0 42px #ffd70080; box-shadow: 0 0 16px #8B008B;}
    80%{top: 351px; text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #ffd70080,  0 0 20px #ffd70080,  0 0 43px #ffd70080; box-shadow: 0 0 17px #8B008B;}
    90%{top: 349px; text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #ffd70080,  0 0 19px #ffd70080,  0 0 44px #ffd70080; box-shadow: 0 0 18px #8B008B;}
    100%{top: 351px; text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #ffd70080,  0 0 18px #ffd70080,  0 0 45px #ffd70080; box-shadow: 0 0 19px #8B008B;}
}

@keyframes MenuMove{
    0%{top: 451;}
    10%{top: 349px;}
    20%{top: 351px;}
    30%{top: 349px;}
    40%{top: 351px;}
    50%{top: 349px;}
    60%{top: 351px;}
    70%{top: 349px;}
    80%{top: 351px;}
    90%{top: 349px;}
    100%{top: 351px;}
}

@keyframes Bye{
    0% {
        background-color: black;
        left: 250px;
        color:#333300; text-shadow: none;
        border-color: #8B008B;
    }    
    30%  {
        background-color: black;
        left: 230px; top: 350px; 
        color:#ffd700; text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ffd700,  0 0 10px #ffd700,  0 0 100px #ffd700; font-size: 43px;
        border-color: #8B008B; box-shadow: 0 0 30px #8B008B;
    }
    45%  {
        background-color: black;
        left: 280px; top: 350px; 
        color:#333300; text-shadow: none;
        border-color: #8B008B80; box-shadow: none;
    }
    
    100%   {
        background-color: black;
        left: -700px; top: 350px; 
        color:#333300; text-shadow: none; 
        border-color: #8B008B80; box-shadow: none;
    }
}

@keyframes ByeOptions{
    0%{
        background-color: black;
        left: 250px; 
        color:#333300; text-shadow: none;
        border-color: #8B008B;
    }    
    30%{
        background-color: black;
        left: 270px;
        color:#ffd700; text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ffd700,  0 0 10px #ffd700,  0 0 100px #ffd700; font-size: 43px;
        border-color: #8B008B; box-shadow: 0 0 10px #8B008B80;
    }
    35%{
        background-color: black;
        left: 220px; 
        color:#333300; text-shadow: none;
        border-color: #8B008B80; box-shadow: none;
    }
    100%{
        background-color: black;
        left: 1400px;
        color:#333300; text-shadow: none;
        border-color: #8B008B80; box-shadow: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pac-Man</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "GameFrame" >
            <a id= "Start">
                START
            </a>
            <a id= "Options">
                OPTIONS
            </a>
            <a id= "Exit">
                EXIT
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pretty nice effects! But im not seeing Options nor Exit do any animation when clicked?

Comment: Hello and thank you for both your comment and your copliment! The animations aren't showing in the stackoverflow compiler, what should i change so its compatible with it?

Comment: Click the full page option and they gonna show!